# 64 bits apps supporting 32 bits and new appstore

Tags: ios, ios11

So ios 11 will break support for 32 apps, thus the older iphones will not be able to upgrade to it.

But what about apps that run in both 64 and 32bits, will they be able to download the app updates or will they be stuck with the last release available at the time of ios 11 release?

I want to know if for a build there is two versions of the app or one version supporting both 32bits and 64bits.
Basically will people with an iphone inferior to 5s be completly cut out of the appstore at this year fall or not.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me, how installing ios 11 beta will allow me to test if an iphone 5 running ios 10 will be able to download future updates of my app?

Comment: If you build your app for both ARMV7 and ARM64 your app will run on both 32 and 64 bit phones. Apps only build with the ARMV7 will not run on iOS 11. All 32 iOS bit devices are stuck on iOS 10 and will not be able to update to iOS 11.

Comment: I already know that mate, that is not what i am asking.

Comment: As stated in my comment, any app build for both 32(ARMv7) and 64(ARM64) bit will run, even if you use iOS 11 SDK. It's just that iOS 11 does not have 32 bit sub system and therefor can not run 32 bit apps. And since bitecode device will only download the 32 or 64 bit slice of your app thus it does not download huge part of you app that are not used.

Comment: Mate i do not care about ios 11 sdk.
What i care about are my customers running ios 10 with 32bits devices.
I updated my question to make it more clear

Comment: You don't seem to understand. There is a difference between OS and SDK. The OS, in this case iOS 11, does not support 32bit. But the SDK for iOS 11 can be used to create 32 bit apps that run on older devices. Otherwise you will have to drop older iOS version if you target iOS 11. Although Apple would like that they will never force you to do this.

Comment: ios 10 sdk can do the same, still doesn't answer my question :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146058/discussion-between-rckoenes-and-thibaut-noah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recap, No older 32 bit devices will not be locked out of the AppStore.

Since iOS 11 will drop support for 32bit, Xcode 9 with the iOS 11 SDK will not. Just don't use any new methods or classes that only exist on iOS 11 if you are also targeting iOS <= 10.